# ISO not booting from WD My Passport Ultra

Tags: windows, boot

I formatted a WD My Passport ultra to NTFS. I checked using PowerISO that the .iso image is indeed bootable. When I plug it in to my Lenovo Laptop I press F12 to bring up the boot options and choose the WD drive. After doing so it tries for a split-second and reloads the menu.

What am I doing wrong?